# No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core with ASP.NET Identity and have the following:

```
User user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(myEmail);

SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, myPassword, true, false);
```

I get a user but when I try to sign in the user I get the error:

```
[Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
```

System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application

On web project Startup file I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {

  // Other configuration code lines

  applicationBuilder.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

  applicationBuilder.UseIdentity();

} // Configure

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

  // Other configuration code lines

  services
    .AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context, Int32>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong. I tried to change the configuration and I always get the same error ...

Any idea?

Comment: applicationBuilder.UseIdentity(); is what should configure the cookie middleware, make sure that line is called before calling app.UseMvc, authentication must be configured before mvc

Comment: Thanks! That was it! I tried everything I could think off but switching was not one of them. You can add your comment as Answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
applicationBuilder.UseIdentity();
```

is what should configure the cookie middleware, make sure that line is called before calling

```
applicationBuilder.UseMvc()
```

authentication must be configured before mvc